# Почему не работает эмулятор в VS

Tags: android, .net, visual-studio, xaml, maui

У меня проблема, не хочет работать эмулятор Андроид в VS. Иногда бывает выскакивает белый экран и постоянная загрузка, но ничего дальше не происходит, в чем дело?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не думаю что это как-то связано с VS. Обновите эмулятор до последней версии, сделайте ему wipe data, cold boot или вообще удалите и создайте заново.